# Implicit conversion not working in template class

Tags: c++, templates, implicit-conversion

I have the following class and when I run test code to test operator/, the compiler tells me the following (referring to the comparison made in the divide operator function)

`C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const foo<8>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

```
template<unsigned int t>
class foo {
  foo(int i) {
    // implicit conversion
  }

  template<unsigned int u>
  bool operator==(const foo<u>& obj) const {
    // do some comparison here
  }

  template<unsigned int u>
  foo operator/(const foo<u>& divisor) const {
    if (divisor == 0)
    // perform division
    // return foo result
  }
};
```

However, when I add the following code into the class, there's no error:

```
friend bool operator==(const foo<t>& lhs, const foo<t>& rhs) {
  // do some comparison here
}
```

My test code looks like this:

```
int main() {
  foo<8> foo_a(0);
  foo<4> foo_b(123);
  foo_b / foo_a;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Edit your code to include a [mcve].

Comment: `friend` declarations must be within a class, not in the global scope.  An `if` statement must have a body.  An operator with a return value must return a value.  After fixing those, I don't see your problem.

Comment: `friend` is within the class, not global. if does have a body (implementation left out because it's not relevant), same goes for return value (left out because irrelevant), but as I'm typing this I realized the issue....

When operator== is called (without the friend function implemented), the template parameter u is unknown and thus the compiler can't figure out the type.

Comment: They may seem irrelevant to you, but if you want help you should include code that compiles in your question, at least to the extent of your ability.  It should be possible for me to copy one block of code from your post and use it to reproduce the problem you have.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is to find `==` in

```
if (divisor == 0)
```

If you only have

```
template<unsigned int u>
bool operator==(const foo<u>& obj) const {
  // do some comparison here
}
```

the compiler cannot figure out if any value of `u` would give us a `foo<u>` that is convertible from `0`. So it doesn't use that operator.

On the other hand, if you have

```
friend bool operator==(const foo<t>& lhs, const foo<t>& rhs) {
  // do some comparison here
}
```

it can see that if `lhs` is `foo<t>` then `rhs` must be that as well. And then it can use the constructor `foo(int i)` to construct a `foo<t>` from the value `0`. And now it has values for both sides of the `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Add explicit to your class constructor and error will come back.

```
explicit foo(int i)
```

What happens is that compiler, try this code:

```
if (divisor == 0)
```

By creating foo object from 0 (it can do that as your constructor is not explicit), but fails, as two foo objects are compared, you did not provide this operator.

When you add function:

```
friend bool operator==(const foo<t>& lhs, const foo<t>& rhs) {
  // do some comparison here
}
```

You do provide necessary operator.